# Can't find a good turbulenz documentation

Tags: turbulenz

I'm just starting with turbulenz and followed some steps from http://docs.turbulenz.com/starter/getting_started_guide.html

Now I want to understand more about some apis, like camera api, and can't find a good documentation about it, I found this: http://docs.turbulenz.com/jslibrary_api/camera_api.html but I need more examples, someone can guide me? For now I need some documentations about camera, floor, creating cube objects and collisions objects. Any good youtuber or website with examples? **I need examples with step by step description**.

Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, but SO isn't the right site for this question. Asking for tutorials or examples is off topic.

Comment: ok, I will try to redo my question.